# Why isn't the requests library working after being installed?

Tags: python

I have imported the requests package (pip install requests) and it shows when I run pip list, but when I run code that uses import requests, it gives me the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'". I've tried updating pip but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: One way or another, you probably have more than one Python environment. Requests is installed in one, and you're running code in another.

Comment: On which platform (linux/mac/windows) are you running? If on Linux or MacOS, where is `pip` installed (see e.g. the output of `which pip`)? Where is `python` installed (`which python`)?

Comment: I am using windows. I'm running the code in Visual Studio Code. The strange thing is this program was working when I originally created it about 4-5 months ago and I haven't really touched it since then. I'm wondering if I need to update the version of python, pip, or somthing else but I'm not sure.

Comment: What happens if you try running the code directly from the shell, instead of in VS Code?